# Create link to "new item" form

Tags: document-library

I have a sharepoint docuemnt library and i'd like to create a link on my homepage that will launch a new item form associated to my list. Does anyone know what the url would be if my document library is named "test?"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it is a document library you to build the following URL

{url3}/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={list-guid}

- Where {url3} is the URL to the site containing the document library e.g. http://servername
- And {list-guid} is the GUID for the document library e.g.{C61C7F01-B778-402E-BCDF-5E2960B45372}. The GUID is in the URL when you are in the Document Library settings page.

If it is a list you need to build this URL

{url1}/NewForm.aspx?Source={url2}

- Where {url1} is the URL to the list for e.g. http://servername/Test
- And {url2} is the URL to redirect back to when the new record has been added for e.g. you homepage URL - This is an optional parameter.

Comment: thanks. b/c i'm using an infopath form the url was actually "http://servername/listname/Forms/template.xsn" but your post got me on the right track. thanks.

Comment: This Source={url2} thing does not work if the url1 and url2 are to the items on different site collections. Do you know how to get around this issue? Vote up nonetheless, great answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes.. I also experienced this issue. If url1 and url2 are on different site collections then redirect doesn't works.

Answer (score 12):

Just add NewForm.aspx (default) to the List URL, eventually replacing AllItems.aspx or whatever is used for the current view.

example:

http://www.myurl.be/Lists/test/NewForm.aspx

Comment: Excellent! This solution seems to be universal enough to work still with ms265 / SharePoint online (as of Dec 2023).

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on the "Add a new item" at the bottom of your list or document library and then paste that as your link.

Comment: "You can right click on the "Add a new item" at the bottom of your list or document library and then paste that as your link" Tried that, nothing happens when I right-click

Comment: Specifically, you need to right click and then choose "Copy Shortcut."

Comment: This does not work for SharePoint online (ms365) in "new experience" settings.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 you should use

```
<site collection url>/lists/<list name>/item/newifs.aspx
```

Example:

```
mySiteUrl/Lists/test/item/newifs.aspx
```

You can also append the source query string parameter to have the submit action take you to another page.

**Note** the NewForm.aspx will still work in 2013 but it will redirect you to this page.