# From root site, link that creates new item in a specific list / link to newform in a specific list - javascript

Tags: list, javascript, newform

I have a teamsite. On the welcome page (root) I want to have a link to newform of a specific list inside the site collection.

When I click on the link I want it to redirect me so I can create a new listelement. Is this possible within a Content editor web part?

I've tried to link to the newform without any luck

```
<a href="http://awesome.com/sites/SITENAME/MASTERDATALIST/Newform.aspx?source=http://awesome.com/site..../allitems.aspx&contenttypeid=0x0000000000&Rootfolder=sites/..">Link</a>
```

**Duplicate**! **Found the answer here**. Remember to edit the HTML to have correct function (OpenNewDialog() instead of OpenNewServiceRequest() )

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863153/sharepoint-add-new-item-button-on-home-page

Comment: I believe you're looking for this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15305/create-link-to-new-item-form

Comment: I tested ur approach works...just remove all the query string

Comment: Hmm strange.. I'll test that as well

Comment: Hmm must have had wrong url or something.. but it works :)