# Link to upload a new document

Tags: sharepoint-server, form, library, html, hyperlink

I have looked to try and link to the "Upload new Document" form for my Shared Documents from my home page but have had a lot of trouble. I am unsure of what other posts are saying when they mention SharePoint Server.

The link to the library whose "Upload new Document" form I want to access is here:

http://companysite.company.com/project/myProject/SharedDocuments/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I have tried to follow this post: [Create link to "new item" form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15305/create-link-to-new-item-form)
but my GUID has '%' signs instead of dashes and I am unsure of what the SharePOint "server" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you refer has your answer, with only a small tweak, if you are in SP2013.  Your url should be as follows:

```
https://yoursite/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

Note that 2013 uses `/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx`, whereas 2010 used `/_layouts/Upload.aspx`.

You can get your library guid by going to the list settings for the library, and looking for `List=%7BXXXXXXXX%2DXXXX%2DXXXX%2DXXXX%2DXXXXXXXXXXXX%7D`.  Note that it contains %7B,%2D and %7D.  These are merely the encoded forms of `{`, `-` and `}` respectively.  You can unencode them using a site like [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), or you can paste that in, so that the url looks like this:

```
https://yoursite/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=%7BXXXXXXXX%2DXXXX%2DXXXX%2DXXXX%2DXXXXXXXXXXXX%7D
```

Either will work.

Comment: Cool! I got it to work... I now only wish that when the document gets checked in that it would go back to the home page

Comment: Add `&Source=<your home page url>` to your url.