# Add Document Redirect

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, hyperlink

I found this very helpful SharePoint.Stackexchange entry on Redirect after a document library is added to a document library but it is not working properly for me.  [HelpfulLink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15305/create-link-to-new-item-form)

I want to add document library to a home page that will redirect back to the home page or the document library.  But instead of redirecting the page it opens the document after clicking save.

http://servername/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={list-guid}

When I append this "?Source={redirect page URL}?" to the URL it produces an error saying that the list does not exist.

Does anyone know what I am missing?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try creating a URl like this:

http://servername/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={list-guid}&Source=redirectpageURL

'&' is used to separate multiple querystring parameters if there is more than one.